# Calendar Report in VB6

Tags: database, vb6

I'm trying to make a report generating calendar, but I don't want to use the Data Environment because it does not accept a Query with a variable in it (e.g. SELECT * FROM Sample_tbl WHERE ID_Number = $ID_No)
where $ID_No is an Input from a Visual Basic Form, how can I generate a Data Report that when the user clicks on a date on the calendar date picker, it would automatically generate a report showing all the records that matches the date the user had just clicked.

http://imageshack.com/a/img661/1913/dBALj1.png

Comment: Curious: why are you using VB6?

Comment: It's my project in Database Management System 1, no wonder you're curious why I'm still using VB6, I'm really bored using VB6

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date_click event for Monthview control..

```
Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
    ' Call to rs loader
    Call loadRecordset(DateClicked)
End Sub
```

where loadRecordset sub could be written like:

```
Private Sub loadRecordset(vDate as Date)
    Dim strQuery as string
    Dim objRs as new ADODB.Recordset

    strQuery = "SELECT *" & _
               " FROM foo" & _
               " WHERE foo.date = '" & vDate & "'"

    'load rs
    objRs.open strQuery, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

End Sub
```